# How to add an element at the end of each array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array which has thousands of rows from google spreadsheet for example:-

`var array = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[1,4,5,6]......]`

I want to add an element lets say "x" end of every array. I need a solution like this :-

`[[1,2,3,4,x],[2,3,4,1,x],[1,4,5,6,x]......]`

How can I achieve this.

Comment: you would use `push`

Comment: but for that I will have to run a for loop which would be time consuming if the data is very large.

Comment: how else do you imagine you could iterate the array?

Comment: looping through all of the items consume time if it is important for you. if not you can use looping through each item and add to that.

Comment: You could just add a column with your x values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Askish has a great answer, but I would like to provide an alternative.

This approach mutates the arrays instead of creating new ones

```js
var array = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[1,4,5,6]];

array.forEach(e => e.push("x"));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: this is also looping through all items.

Comment: Yes it is, but I never claimed that it isn't

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[1,4,5,6]];

var newArray = array.map(x => [...x, 'x']);

console.log(newArray);
```